# Events not shown in fullcalendar (play framework)

Tags: javascript, java, playframework, fullcalendar, playframework-2.3

I am adding a Calendar to my Play java app using FullCalendar, I just need to show my events in a calendar. for that, I have a JavaScript router, this is my Controller:

```
public class Utilities extends Controller {

 public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
            Routes.javascriptRouter("myJsRoutes",
                    routes.javascript.Utilities.json()
            )
    );
 }

 public static Result json(Long start, Long end) throws ParseException {

    ArrayList<Map<Object, Serializable>> allEvents = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Serializable>>();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    Date startDate = df.parse("2015-08-14 00:00");
    Date endDate = df.parse("2015-08-19 00:00");

    Map<Object, Serializable> eventRemapped = new HashMap<Object, Serializable>();
    eventRemapped.put("id", 1l);
    eventRemapped.put("title", "test title");
    eventRemapped.put("start", df.format(startDate));
    eventRemapped.put("end", df.format(endDate));
    eventRemapped.put("allDay", true);
    allEvents.add(eventRemapped);

    return ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(allEvents));
 }

}
```

and I have this line in the header of my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Utilities.javascriptRoutes()'></script>
```

and this 2 lines in my routes

```
 GET           /javascriptRoutes                         controllers.Utilities.javascriptRoutes

 GET           /events.json                              controllers.Utilities.json(start: Long ?= 0, end: Long ?= 0 )
```

and finally this is my java script code that should show me my test Event from the `Utilities.json`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
            height: 420,
            events: {
                async: false, // tried with and without, just to make sure problem is something else
                url:myJsRoutes.controllers.Utilities.json().ajax({}),
                cache: false
            }
        })
    })
```

Using debugger , I can see that the Utilities.json is being called. but still i do not have any event in my calendar view. it looks just empty:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have to mention that I'm not very familiar with the Javascript world.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the parameters passed to my `Utilities.json` are not parsing as `Long`, but they have to be `String`. so I changed the

```
public static Result json(Long start, Long end) throws ParseException {
```

to

```
public static Result json(String start, String end) throws ParseException {
```

and also changed my routes to:

```
GET           /events.json                              controllers.Utilities.json(start: String, end: String)
```

I also realized that I do not need a Javascript router , so I changed my javascript code to this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
            height: 420,
            events: "/events.json"
        })
    })
```

and things are working fine now